# pma_history creation error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

From documentation, I'm creating `pma_history` table.

This is the only part of `scripts/create_tables.sql` that fails:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_history` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `db` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `timevalue` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  `sqlquery` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `username` (`username`,`db`,`table`,`timevalue`)
)
  ENGINE=MyISAM COMMENT='SQL history for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

This is what server says:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near '(14) NOT NULL, `sqlquery` text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
KEY `user' at line 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the length of the `timestamp` column

```
`timevalue` timestamp NOT NULL
```

> Prior to version 4.1, the format in which MySQL retrieves and displays TIMESTAMP values depends on the display size

Taken from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/timestamp-pre-4-1.html)